# Add black overlay on screen gradually over time when changing screen

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Here's what i have done: when user clicks on button on screen one, the screen one goes to the left slowly and screen two comes from the right towards the center on top of screen one. And then when user clicks on button on screen two, the screen two goes to the right and screen one comes back to the center.

Here is the screen recording:
https://youtube.com/shorts/vlIdVjJPzE8?feature=share

But what I want along with this is, when the screen one is going to the left, i want to add a black overlay on top of it over time. It will go from transparent to black. And when the user goes back from screen two to screen one, the overlay will go from black to nothing(transparent) overtime.

How do I accomplish this?

Below is the code.

```
package com.example.jetpackcomposebasics

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentTransitionScope
import androidx.compose.animation.EnterTransition
import androidx.compose.animation.ExitTransition
import androidx.compose.animation.core.EaseIn
import androidx.compose.animation.core.EaseOut
import androidx.compose.animation.core.tween
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApp()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyApp(){
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = "ScreenOne",
        enterTransition = { EnterTransition.None },
        exitTransition = { ExitTransition.None }
    ){
        composable(
            "ScreenOne",
            enterTransition = {
                slideIntoContainer(
                    animationSpec = tween(300, easing = EaseIn),
                    towards = AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.End
                )
            },
            exitTransition = {
                slideOutOfContainer(
                    animationSpec = tween(1000, easing = EaseOut),
                    towards = AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Start
                )
            }
        ){
            ScreenOne(navController)
        }
        composable(
            "ScreenTwo",
            enterTransition = {
                slideIntoContainer(
                    animationSpec = tween(300, easing = EaseIn),
                    towards = AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Start
                )
            },
            exitTransition = {
                slideOutOfContainer(
                    animationSpec = tween(300, easing = EaseOut),
                    towards = AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.End
                )
            }

        ){
            ScreenTwo(navController)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ScreenOne(navController: NavController){

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Red),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    ){
        Button(
            onClick = {
                navController.navigate("ScreenTwo")
            }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Go To Screen Two")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ScreenTwo(navController: NavController){
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Green),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ){
        Button(
            onClick = { navController.popBackStack() }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Go To Screen One")
        }
    }
}
```